# Using a variable as a clause in a If statement

Tags: excel, vba, class, if-statement

I would ideally like to create a `if` statement where the clause is wheter or not a variable has a value. Currently I have the code below.

```
If UpdateLimit = vbNo Then
    Limit = InputBox("Please set a line distance limit")
Else
    If LimitNow = vbNo Then
        Limit = InputBox("Please set a line distance limit")     
    End If
```

Which works fine but I would like to change the nested `If` statement to something like

```
If Limit (Has Value)) then
    'Do thing 1 
Else 
    Limit= InputBox("Please set a line distance limit") 
End if
```

The idea behind this is that on the first run through you define a limit value but the second run through you dont need to. There may be a  better way to do this, but `LimitNow` and `UpdateLimit` wont be changed on subsequent run throughs

Comment: What datatype are you expecting and what, in this instance, is Limit? You could test if .value = vbNullString  or Limit = vbNullString

Comment: `Limit` qill just be a number so i guess that could work. I'll have a play with it

Comment: It looks like you are expecting a string. If it were a number it would be initialised as 0 before assignment.

Comment: Right, so if i say something like `If Limit = 0  then` would that work?

Comment: Except in cases where the assigned value is 0

Comment: Cool, that will never be the case. Thank you QHarr

Comment: is it `VBA` or `vb.net`?

Comment: VBA, didnt notice the VBA.Net tag thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but maybe a simple class could be used here? HTH

> Class Module `Limit`

```
Private m_value As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_value = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Value() As Integer
    If Not HasValue Then
        Err.Raise "Limit doesn't have any number"
    End If
    Value = CInt(m_value)
End Property

Public Property Let Value(ByVal vNewValue As Integer)
    m_value = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get HasValue() As Boolean
    HasValue = IsNumeric(m_value)
End Property
```

> Standard Module

```
Sub test()
    Dim l As Limit
    Set l = New Limit

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim v As Integer
    v = l.Value ' Error here, limit doesn't have value yet

    On Error GoTo 0

    l.Value = 100
    If l.HasValue Then
        'Do thing 1
    Else
        l.Value = Application.InputBox("Please set a limit value", Type:=1)
    End If
End Sub
```